# Determine the number of different substrings in a string in c++ and using hashing

Tags: c++, hash, substring, inverse, modular

```
int count_unique_substrings(string const& s) {
    int n = s.size();
    const int p = 31;
    const int m = 1e9 + 9;
    vector<long long> p_pow(n);
    p_pow[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        p_pow[i] = (p_pow[i-1] * p) % m;

    vector<long long> h(n + 1, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        h[i+1] = (h[i] + (s[i] - 'a' + 1) * p_pow[i]) % m;

    int cnt = 0;

    for (int l = 1; l <= n; l++) {
        set<long long> hs;

        for (int i = 0; i <= n - l; i++) {
            long long cur_h = (h[i + l] + m - h[i]) % m;
            cur_h = (cur_h * p_pow[n-i-1]) % m;  // unable to understand this line (how it works ?)
            hs.insert(cur_h);
        }

        cnt += hs.size();
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

The problem is the hash for the sub string of length l should be this:

```
((h[i+l] - h[i])/p_pow[i])
```

but the code uses:

```
long long cur_h = (h[i + l] + m - h[i]) % m;
cur_h = (cur_h * p_pow[n-i-1]) % m;
```

Comment: Your variable naming is unclear, please use significant names that improves the code readability.

Comment: The question here is more one of number theory. m and p are both prime and so you're looking for properties of modular groups. It's a bit hard to parse your code because the naming is awkward and could be more clear, but my guess is that the code is correct if someone provided it to you as an example to learn from and using the modular properties to avoid doing division (once upon a time division was like 4x slower than other arithmetic operations). In modular arithmetic a/b mod n = a * u mod n where u * b = 1 mod n .

Comment: Thank you For the answer. But I didn't get the last line that how u*b = 1 mod n